# Where should i write the client side code for socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am a beginner to node.js and more so , to socket.io. In node.js, there is no need for any client side code as far as i know. We can simply connect to the server by pointing the browser to http://localhost:port.

But, in the case of socket.io, there seems to be client side code. But, where should i write this ? Should i write this in a html file and host it from a normal http server? I am a bit confused about the basic architecture itself and i couldnt find this basic explanation anywhere. Please do bear with me

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently wrote a very simple chat application with Node.js and Socket.IO.  Like the above comment, you can use express to server your HTML by configuring a static directory:

```js
app.configure(function() {
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
});
```

See the full code here: https://github.com/pifantastic/stupid-simple-chat/blob/master/server.js

****EDIT****

I should add, in Socket.IO > 0.7, you can serve the socket.io JS library straight out of Node.js, it lives at /socket.io/socket.io.js:

```html
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. But, i dont understand what u mean by "serve your html by configuring a static directory". Can you just tell me what u mean by that?

Comment: Express uses Connect which provides as Middleware a simple static file server.  You have to configure it to know which directory you want to serve static files from.  In my example above, I'm telling express to serve static fles from the current directory.  That way I can place my index.html file right along side my server.js file so it can be served from node.

Comment: Thanks a lot. now,i am able to serve plain html pages. However, if i use socket.io client in the html page, i get an info in server log that "client protocol unsupported". I guess this error has something to do with transport protocol being used. Did u have this error when u wrote socket.io client html pages for ur chat application?

Comment: What version of the node.js Socket.IO module are you running?

Comment: I am running node0.4.9 and socket.io 0.7

Answer (score 1):

First if you're not using [express](http://expressjs.com/) you probably should be. Among other things it's a static file server so you can put your client side JavaScripts into `/public/javascripts` and use them from `http://localhost:port/javascripts/myscript.js`

Here's a hello world example http://codr.cc/s/2376dc51/js

Comment: thx for the link. But, when i pointed the browser to myscrips.js, i get the content of the javascript file as plain text. its not executing the javascript

Comment: that's normal.  You'll need to add it into an html file. I updated the link with an example html file.

Comment: Doesnt work still. now, i get nothing ... I loaded the html file from the browser. firebug gave no error ,whatsoever. The page is just empty. :( I still cant figure out how to write client code and make it communicate with the server